# Calling function from already deployed contract in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I want to know how to call a function from already deployed contract in solidity. I tried below one but it's throwing error and require without imorting the deployed contract

```
 contract B {
    watch_addr = 0x1245689;
    function register(string _text) {
        watch_addr.call(bytes4(keccak256("register(string)")), _text);
    }
}
```

Can any one please tell me the solution?

```
error:browser/delegate.sol:14:31: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from bytes4 to bytes memory requested. This function requires a single bytes argument. If all your arguments are value types, you can use abi.encode(...) to properly generate it.
       watch_addr.call(bytes4(keccak256(abi.encode("register(string)"))));
```

Answer (score 4):

In version 5.0 Solidity had some [breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/050-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes):

> The functions **.call()** ... now accept only a single bytes argument. Moreover, the argument is not padded. This was changed to make more explicit and clear how the arguments are concatenated. Change ... every **.call(signature, a, b, c)** to use **.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(signature, a, b, c))** (the last one only works for value types). ... Even though it is not a breaking change, it is suggested that developers change **x.call(bytes4(keccak256("f(uint256)"), a, b)** to **x.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("f(uint256)", a, b))**.

So, the suggested way to call other contract is like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.3;

contract test3 {       
    address watch_addr = address(0x1245689);
    function register(string memory _text) public {
        watch_addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("register(string)", _text));
    }
}
```

Also note added `memory` keyword: you now need to specify data location for function parameters of complex types:

> Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters and return variables.